# Disk space Postgres database gets full eventhough Vacuum

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.5, vacuum

I have a database which is constantly written by different servers. The problem I have is that even though I `vacuum` the database, the disk available is progressively in time getting reduced. This is an image of a 16 day period:

[image]

As you see the trend is decreasing the memory available.
If I zoom in on a certain interval:

[image]

I can see that that at some point in time the VACUUM happens (I guess it is the pick going down even though it does not make much sense as it should go up instead of down).

I have a configuration in `/etc/cron.daily/<database name>` as:

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

LIMIT=$(date -d '-2 months' +'%Y-%m-%dT00:00:00')

CMD="delete from source_stat where slot < '$LIMIT'"
su postgres -c "psql datacare -c \"$CMD\""

CMD="delete from request_stat where slot < '$LIMIT'"
su postgres -c "psql datacare -c \"$CMD\""

CMD="delete from perf_stat where slot < '$LIMIT'"
su postgres -c "psql datacare -c \"$CMD\""

su postgres -c "psql datacare -c VACUUM"
```

to remove data older than 2 months, and this works. Then, I do not understand why on average the free disk size gets reduced. Insertions in the database are pretty constant in time so if older data gets removed it should counteract new data coming in. Moreover, it does not make much sense that I have moments with flat steep and moments with high steep.

Postgres version: `PostgreSQL 9.5.7`

Comment: No, the problem is that it gets fulled with time but I do not know where does it come from

Comment: I have edited the question

Comment: That seems to be a disk space, not a memory problem. Check if the `pg_xlog` directory is growing.

Comment: You are right. I meant disk. It does not increase, the maximum value is 16

Comment: Ok, then figure out which files are growing.

Comment: "Moreover, it does not make much sense that I have moments with flat steep and moments with high steep."  That part makes sense.  After a vacuum, it can reuse that space, so while it is doing so the disk usage will be flat.

Comment: Use OS tools to figure out where the data is being used.  Like on linux, `du -Sh $PGDATA |sort -rh`